# Get executed SQL from Spring's NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

I want to know how to get the sql that will be executed before (or that was executed afeter) calling "update" method.

For example:

```
String SQL = "DELETE FROM familias WHERE codFamilia = :codFamilia";
MapSqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
paramSource.addValue("codFamilia", familia.getCodFamilia());

namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(SQL, paramSource);
```

I would like to add a sentence like:

```
System.out.println(namedParameterJdbcTemplate.getExecutedSQL());
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I can use this:

String sqlToUse = NamedParameterUtils.substituteNamedParameters(parsedSql, paramSource);

I'm checking it out.

Comment: Its search for `?` and not `:foo`